# Python Selenium scraping Microsoft Teams Website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-teams

I am trying to scrape a Microsoft Teams (Web App) site listing assignments.

```py
import os
import pprint
import time

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

load_dotenv()


usernameStr = os.environ.get('EMAIL')
passwordStr = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=os.environ.get('HOME')+"/myConky/scripts/chromedriver"
)
browser.get(
    '<link to teams webpage>'
)
# Email input field
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'i0116')
    )
)
username = browser.find_element_by_id('i0116')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

# Click the next button
browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()

#Input field for password
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'i0118')
    )
)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('i0118')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

# sleep for sometime beacuse there is some overlay
time.sleep(2)
#click the submit button
element = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
# again same reason
time.sleep(2)
#click Yes button
element = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()

# time to load the Assignments page
# time.sleep(25)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.XPATH,
            '//*[@id="list-view-current-day"]/div/div'
        )
    )
)
assignments = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="list-view-current-day"]/div/div'
)
print(assignments)
```

[Assignment Page Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mmKo.png)

[Html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Q8F.png)

after that `a` tag I'm selecting the 2nd inner div nested inside it

the error i get on line 53-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<username>/myConky/scripts/get_teams_assignment.py", line 53, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  File "/home/<username>/.local/share/virtualenvs/myConky-kSysQeVB/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

And the `Message` field is blank

this corresponds to the code-snippet:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.XPATH,
            '//*[@id="list-view-current-day"]/div/div'
        )
    )
)
```

Also, when I try to query the entire body of the page

```py
time.sleep(30)
assignments = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body'
)

for x in assignments : 
    print(x.text)
```

I get-

[Output terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krtqt.png)

How do I fix this

Comment: Please avoid linking screenshots and show the output directly as text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual answer.

if you can see the html tabs in your browser inspection tool and you can't utilize it with selenium with exception errors then there will more than likely be an iframe. Double check by finding all iframes. Crazy enough, your code is very similar to mine so I basically replicated your issue and I'll use your code with what you need:

```
import os
import pprint
import time

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

load_dotenv()


usernameStr = os.environ.get('EMAIL')
passwordStr = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=os.environ.get('HOME')+"/myConky/scripts/chromedriver"
)
browser.get(
    '<link to teams webpage>'
)
# Email input field
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'i0116')
    )
)
username = browser.find_element_by_id('i0116')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

# Click the next button
browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()

#Input field for password
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'i0118')
    )
)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('i0118')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

# sleep for sometime beacuse there is some overlay
time.sleep(2)
#click the submit button
element = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
# again same reason
time.sleep(2)
#click Yes button
element = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()

# time to load the Assignments page
# time.sleep(25)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.embedded-electron-webview.embedded-page-content"    
        )
    )
)
iframeElement = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.embedded-electron-webview.embedded-page-content")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframeElement)
# ...
# do stuff here!
# ...

browser.switch_to.default_content #to back out of iframe if needed.
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this :

```
assignments = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-view-current-day"]/div/div')
```

you will have python list.

now you can iterate this list in n number of ways :

```
for assignment in assignments:
    print(assignment.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

should print what you have been looking for.

Comment: But the error is in the WebDriverWait command, giving Timeout Exception

Comment: Did you run the code ? Webdriver wait throws only common exception.

Comment: Yes update your question with error stack trace, Just copy paste.

Comment: See `WebDriverWait` will throw common exception, we will never get to know the root cause. Simply replace driver.find_element, and then share the error stack trace once again

Comment: that gives no errors but neither does it give an output for `assignment.get_attribute('innerText')` 
and the `assignments` list is empty